# Swift Playground error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

How to even debug this error? There seems to be no additional error description to it.

The code that fails:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.addConstraint(.init(item: stackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
stackView.addConstraint(.init(item: stackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView // error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
```

Full error:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT. The process
> has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread
> return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Full console log:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: I think that's because you're adding the constraints before the View is actually in the hierarchy

Comment: @aheze I tried to move the liveView assignment line right after the containerView initialization, but now the same error appears at the constraints addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the constraint to `stackView` rather than `containerView`.

The [documentation for `addConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622523-addconstraint) states

> The constraint to be added to the view. The constraint may only reference the view itself or its subviews.

`containerView` is the super view of `stackView`, not a sub view.

If you change your code to add the constraint to the `containerView` it will run

```
containerView.addConstraint(.init(item: stackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
containerView.addConstraint(.init(item: stackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

You will probably want to add a trailing and a bottom constraint so that the stack view fills the whole container view.  You will, of course, also need to add an `arrangedSubview` so that there is actually some content in the stack view.

It is generally simpler to add constraints by referencing layout guides rather than this older, more verbose, approach:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(stackView)

stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Hello world"
label.textColor = .black
stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = containerView
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. The only main question remains is how to debug this kinds of errors?